# Multiple self-referencing foreign key

Tags: database, oracle11g

I want to create a mapping table like this:

```
MIS_REPORT_STRUC_MAIN
(
  m_id          NVARCHAR2(3) not null,
  m_name        NVARCHAR2(200),
  main_head     NVARCHAR2(3),
  sub_head      NVARCHAR2(3),
  tot_head      NVARCHAR2(3),
  sub_tot_head  NVARCHAR2(3)
);
```

Where `M_ID` will be the primary key and `MAIN_HEAD`, `SUB_HEAD`, `TOT_HEAD`, `SUB_TOT_HEAD` will be self-referencing foreign keys.

Please help me to write the SQL.

If it should not be possible, then explain why.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
select * from MIS_REPORT_STRUC_MAIN t
left outer join MIS_REPORT_STRUC_MAIN t_mh on t.main_head = t_mh.m_id
left outer join MIS_REPORT_STRUC_MAIN t_sh on t.main_head = t_sh.m_id
left outer join MIS_REPORT_STRUC_MAIN t_th on t.main_head = t_th.m_id
left outer join MIS_REPORT_STRUC_MAIN t_sth on t.main_head = t_sth.m_id
```

Comment: I want to create table